# I want to call third party API using fetch-node( ) but I am getting error require( ) ES module. I am new to nodejs

Tags: node.js, api

```
const express= require('express');
const fetch= require('node-fetch');
const app= express();

app.listen(3000, () =>{
  console.log('starting server at port 3000');
});
```

// to enable parsing of json object in the body of request

```
app. use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

//API to call another API i.e third party API

```
app.get('/project', async(req,res)=>{
```

//third party URL
const api_url= 'https://api.fyre.hypersign.id/api/v1/project/demo-event-001?isPublic=true';
const fetch_response= await fetch(api_url);
const result= await fetch_response.json();
res.json(result);

});

Answer (score 1):

You can not load an ES module as a CommonJS module. The code causing the error is `require('node-fetch')`. You must be using v3+ of `node-fetch` which is [ESM-only](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/releases/tag/v3.0.0).

Use [v2.6.5](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/tree/v2.6.5) of `node-fetch` which supports CommonJS or change your app to use `import` instead of `require`.